# Материал для создания успешного IT-бизнеса

Tags: it-бизнес, работа, книги

Собственно сабж. 
Что рекомендуете почитать, поразбирать для создания успещного бизнеса в сфере IT(но не только)? Законы, статьи, книги, сайты(кроме Хабра:) по предпринимательству и управлению проектами, персоналом. Суть в том, чтобы не запаривать себе голову всякой ерундой, а понять типичные ошибки, разобрать законы и примерный путь. Предположим идея такая: разработка и продажа собственного ПО.

Поделитесь своим опытом. Что помогло вам?

Comment: Заечм было писать "Или на хэшкоде только программисты, работающие на дядю?"... ИМХО некрасиво...

Comment: Сорри, сказывается моя работа...поправил

Comment: 1. Главное - оригинальная идея, предложение, которым можно подцепить покупателя.
2. Предпринимателем нельзя стать, им надо родиться. Если Вы чувствуете в себе такое призвание - тогда вперед. А книги - дело второе. Главное - чувствовать ход дело.

Comment: Многие даже ВО не имеют и делают деньги "с ветра", тут книги не помогут, что касается призвания - солидарен с @mikillskegg

Comment: The late Стив Джобс тоже не имел ВО

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Жилу нужно иметь, жилу!!! Книги не помогут, ибо нет уникальной идеи, нет бизнеса. ИМХО!

Comment: Сама идея не стоит ничего... За нее надо боротся и реализовывать...<br>
Идей миллионы, миллионеров еденицы...

Comment: Да, тут важна мотивация и собственно команда. Слаженная команда. Но нужно понимать заранее что делаешь и как это выводить на рынок. Кроме того нужно сам рынок изучать и понимать. Много всего вообщем, по идеи. Но есть наверняка примерная последовательность действий, которую и хочется понять.

Comment: Ну суть же не продать идею, а реализовать самому! Миллионеры тоже с чего-то начинали!(хотя начинали они с 90-х xD)

Comment: Без реального опыта вы ничего не поймете, ИМХО

Comment: согласен на 110%

Comment: Банально, даже при опыте, мотивации и отличной идее как минимум необходим стартовый капитал + хотя-бы 1 высококвалифицированый специалист и хотя-бы 2 уровнем незначительно пониже ( чтобы было "от чего отталкиватся" и у кого спришивать "дешевым" рабочим )...<br>
Если вы считаете что программисты не проблема при наличчи капитала ( не утверждаю, лигь предпологаю ), то вы очень сильно ошибаетесь...

Comment: Cовсем забыл - главный материал это мозг :)<br>
тут вам книги и советы великой истины не откроют...<br>
многие знают как заработать миллион, но зарабатывают "еденицы" :)

Comment: То что Вы говорите понятно и тем не менее есть законы и материал, который стоит изучить, чтобы избежать типичных ошибок!

Comment: Главное хорошие знакомые среди заказчиков (покупателей) Ваших проектов. Обычно они покупают не за свои деньги, а прибыль Вы делите с ними.

Comment: Знакомые эти не мои знакомые, как Вы понимаете:)

Answer (score -1):

Для начала нужно придумать что-то, что еще не создано, но о чем потребитель мечтает, пусть даже еще не сознавая это.

Comment: вовсе не обязательно, если, конечно, под успешным IT бизнесом не подразумеваются миллиардные состояния...

Comment: Первый закон бизнеса - хорошо изучить потребности рынка и найти то, что на нем востребовано. Производство ПО - это не сосиски у метро продавать. И не сфера услуг, которые все время востребованы. Рынок ПО очень обширен, на нем много компаний с большими ресурсами и историей, а также доверием у потребителя. Продуктов предлагается немерено. И если не будет предложено что-то оригинальное, что будет реально покупаться, то бизнес провалиться. ПУсть это будет не что-то совсем новое, но должна быть изюминка в чем-то: интерфейсе, функционале и т.д. А работать сутками за копейки...

Comment: Между изюминкой и чем-то пренципиально новым есть огромная разница, не находите? :)

Comment: И еще насчет миллиардных доходов. Плох тот солдат, которые не мечтает стать генералом. Затевать бизнес ради копеечных доходов - нерационально. Бизнес требует огромных сил, и если не будет отдачи, то зачем и затевать...

Кстати, расчитывать на российский рынок очень трудно. Не привыкли у нас покупать ПО. Надо мыслить изначально о выходе на международный масштаб.

Comment: Причем тут генерал, причем тут солдат, Вы а чем?<br>
У вас есть идея на миллионы?<br>так чего же вы сдесь на хэш-коде делаете тогда? :)<br>
Я гдето писал о бизнесе ради копеечных доходов?<br>
Нет, если вам нравится строить какието илюзии и верить в Божьи дары и  в то что "если я буду честно работать - все будет ок, будут и деньги и удовольствие от работы и т.д." - вперед...<br>
Я лишь высказываю свое мнение, а Вы воспринимаете его как-юудто бы я вам что-то запрещаю или навязываюсь :)<br><br>
<small>Во избежание недорозумений - адресовано @mikillskegg</small>

Comment: У меня нет таких идей, и поэтому я не занимаюсь бизнесом. И другим не советую, если у них их нет.

Comment: Потом, человек задал вопрос: "Что нужно для успешного бизнеса в IT?" Я высказал свои соображения. А дальше пусть сам думает.

Я немного занимался бизнесом, и знаю что это такое. Если уж заниматься, то только ради больших денег и перспектив. Иначе даже не стоит и начинать.

Comment: И этот человек мне пишет о " Плох тот солдат, которые не мечтает стать генералом", не мне судить, конечно, но "помоему" вы немного непостоянны в своих высказываниях :)<br>
Цитата "Иначе даже не стоит и начинать"... Не буду оригинальным, но все-же - под лежачий кaмень...<br> Если этого не понимать то ни денег ни успеха ждать не приходится ( конечно если вам не завещали огромное нследство ^^ )